# Pager toolbar in custom module in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I use this [tutorial](http://asia-connect.com.vn/2009/07/magento-filter-by-multiple-categories/) and display products on the basis of multiple categories but now I am getting in issue is that the pager tool bar not working on that.
My block code is :

```
<reference name="content"> 
    <block name="mymodule" type="mymodule/product_listcategories"  template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
        <action method="setCategories">
            <ids>2,3,4</ids>
        </action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

I also add this code with above

```
<block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
    </block>
    <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
</block>
```

It display toolbar but the toolbar is not working (limit,orderby).
My block code is

```
class Mymodule_Block_Product_Listcategories extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
{
    protected function _getProductCollection()
    {

        $this->_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        $this->_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

        if($this->getCategories()!="")
            $this->_productCollection->addCategoriesFilter($this->getCategories());

            return $this->_productCollection;
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know where is the problem? I think I'm missing some code for the pager? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After search so much i got a solution.I didn't know whether it right or wrong way but it solve my problem.On my block i create intance of 
`$cpBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlockSingleton('Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar');`
and access the pager core function like  `$this->_itemPerPage =  $cpBlock->getLimit();` .In the above code itemperpage is the total no of items to be displayed on listing page.This code work if you create custom module and extend you block from list block.Thanks